# How do I get StructuredProperty's in Google App Engine to update?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, app-engine-ndb

I have a Player model that is assigned to a Team.  When I assign them to a Team I see the correct team name show up when I access player.team.name.  If I go to the Team and rename it, the player.team.name still returns the old team name.

1. A player is assigned to "New Orleans Hornets".  The player.team.name is "New Orleans Hornets".
2. Rename "New Orleans Hornets" team to "New Orleans Pelicans".  The player.team.name is still "New Orleans Hornets".

Code:

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Player(ndb.Model):
  name = ndb.StringProperty()
  team = ndb.StructuredProperty(Team)
```

I have a feeling I need to use a KeyProperty here but can't figure out how that would work.  Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The StructuredProperty stores the Team entity within the Player entity (ie.It has a copy of the team). So you would need to find each Player who is a member of the team and updated the Player.team entry with the new name.

Using a KeyProperty will store a reference to the Team entity. When retrieving a Player, you will need to do a separate get call to retrieve the associated Team.

The model will look something like:

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
   name = ndb.StringProperty()

class Player(ndb.Model):
   name = ndb.StringProperty()
   team = ndb.KeyProperty(kind=Team)
```

To store a Player with a team:

```
team = #look up an existing team entity
player = Player()
player.name = "Joe"
player.team = team.key() 
player.put()
```

To retrieve a Player with their team name you would:

```
player = ....
players_team = Team.get_by_id(player.team)
players_team.name # to access the name
```